# Is StrongLoop a Rest API builder or a deployment tool?

Tags: node.js, deployment

In the documenation says that is a set of Node.js modules used for building rest APIs

Although here :

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-deploy-production-best-practice/

says that is a tool that can help you deploy any node app using **strong-build** , 
**strong-deploy and strong-pm** modules.

Can someone shed some light on this confusion ?
If is used for deployments of node.js apps is there any straight forward documentation explaining how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

StrongLoop is the name of the *company* - the REST API framework that they provide is called LoopBack.

LoopBack, `strong-build`, `strong-deploy` and `strong-pm` are all separate tools, but are all accessed using the [StrongLoop command-line tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strongloop), which can be accessed using the `slc` command.

Comment: So basically is it something similar to PM2 process manager ? Or does it offers capabilities such as managing and packaging dependencies and pushing deployments to git repos before sending them to the process manager ?

Comment: @AlexLemesios: Based on my (very) limited knowledge of StrongLoop's tools, `strong-pm` on its own is similar to PM2. `strong-build` handles packaging, `strong-deploy` handles pushing deployments to the process manager.